# Limpieza total de etiqueta div

Tags: ajax, highcharts, div

Buenas tardes a todos, estoy trabajando con unos gráficos de highcharts, todo trabaja bien, pero tengo un problema.
Estoy utilizando Ajax para crear todos los charts, sin embargo el chart de "pie" tiene ciertos "errorcitos" que no me dejan hacerlo tan dinámico. A lo que voy, Cuando mando a llamar una función que me crea el chart lo hace correctamente, se puede elegir el mes que se quiere consultar, pero cuando cambian de mes, ya responde.
Me dí cuenta que los JS´s de high charts le ponen información adicional al  donde estoy mandando a llamar todo. he tratado de limpiarlo en cuando inicia mi función con:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
```

Pero no lo hace, he explorado un poco con las herramientas de desarrollador y tengo esto en el div cuando ya hay una gráfica:

```
 <div id="container" data-highcharts-chart="0"></div>
```

¿Alguien me puede decir como hacer una limpieza total del div?

Anexo fotos correspondientes.
[image]
Así se ve el código cuando aún no he hecho nada.

[image]
Así se ve cuando ya mandé a llamar una gráfica, todo va perfecto. Este por ejemplo es el mes de Julio, toda esa información que se pone, quiero suponer que es lo que se anexa como parte del funcionamiento de la gráfica

[image]
Así se ve cuando quiero mandar a llamar Marzo, ya no lo hace y no muestra la gráfica.
Como podrán ver ya no tiene nada el div, pero se quedo con ciertas etiquetas dentro.

Gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Al usar `document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";` ¿genera algún error?

Comment: No, ninguno, limpia todo lo que trae dentro, pero no las propiedades del tag como tal. :(

Comment: ¿puedes actualizar la pregunta agregando un pantallazo "antes" y "después" de que hayas realizado esta acción? Por favor, añade con mas detalle esos "errores" que comentas en tu pregunta. Yo haría también esta prueba: Intenta vaciar el div superior al div `container` y genera nuevamente el chart.

Comment: Añadido, gracias. De hecho, cuando entra la función se limpian los divs aledaños al que está recibiendo todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero alguna de las siguientes opciones:

1. Generar un elemento HTML de tipo `div` que contenga a su vez el div `container` que usas para la gráfica.

Ejemplo:

```
<div id='divContenedorPadre'>
    <div id="container" data-highcharts-chart="0"></div>    
</div>
```

Luego, ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
// Vacia el DIV contenedor padre y luego genera el DIV 'container'.
document.getElementById("divContenedorPadre").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("divContenedorPadre").innerHTML = "<div id=\"container\"></div>";
```

2. Puedes usar [removeAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) junto con el código proporcionado por el usuario [Miguel Osorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17096/78):

`document.getElementById("container").removeAttribute("data-highcharts-chart");`

*Nota: no se realmente si es la mejor práctica, pero genera los resultados esperados.*

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió tu aportación aunque completé unas cosas. Ya lo limpia todo, y cuando lo mando a llamar no regresa nada. Le puse un trigger para que se ejecutara el código en cuanto llegara y ya lo hace. Ahora hay otro problema.... La información no cambia, si veo que se recarga pero aunque cambie de meses por que tiene información diferente siempre me trae el mes que seleccione desde el principio.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió tu aportación aunque completé unas cosas. Ya lo limpia todo. Ahora hay otro problema.... La información no cambia, si veo que se recarga pero aunque cambie de meses por que tiene información diferente siempre me trae el mes que seleccione desde el principio. En las herramientas de desarrollador puedo ver como se limpian y se vuelven a llenar los divs, solo que detecté algo raro
    data-highcharts-chart="0"
el número dentro incrementa de 1 en 1.
¿Habrá forma de limpiar quizá la memoria o algo por el estilo?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob, ¿qué tan a menudo se debe limpiar el div? Sugiero consultar la documentación de Highcharts para conocer el propósito del valor `data-highcharts-chart=0`. Dejo a tu criterio seleccionar esta respuesta como la respuesta correcta a tu inquietud principal.
Saludos.

Comment: Siempre se debe de limpiar, la función entra en el onchange del select. Pero tienes razón veré cual es el propósito de dicho tag. Agradezco tu atención y ahí esta tu cerveza :P

Answer (score 1):

Usando jquery

```
  $(function() {
    $("#container").empty ();
 });
```

Esto te limpia por completo el div

Comment: Te daria un ejemplo completo pero ando desde el movil

Comment: Limpia lo que trae adentro, pero no lo que tiene dentro de los tags.
https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Igualmente gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sencilla, seria reemplazar el div por uno nuevo manteniendo las propiedades que quieras, como por ejemplo el id.
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de función.

```js
function limpiaDiv(id) {
  var viejoDiv = document.getElementById(id)
  var nuevoDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  nuevoDiv.id = viejoDiv.id;
  viejoDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(nuevoDiv, viejoDiv);
}
document.write(primero.getAttribute("data-highcharts-chart"), "<br>");
limpiaDiv("primero");
document.write(primero.getAttribute("data-highcharts-chart"));
```

```html
<DIV id="primero" data-highcharts-chart="0">Contenido</div>
```